# Why in calculating 25 mM of Tris HCl the answer in gram is automatically refer to the gram in 1000 ml

Tags: physical-chemistry, analytical-chemistry, physical-organic-chemistry

In the lab class,my teacher told me that the answer i get in grams is automatically the grams in 1000 ml.

Why is it possible without we doing anything the grams i get automatically the grams in 1000 ml?

For example

If i want to find how much Tris HCl powder i need for 25 mM

I did 25/1000 mol * 121.14 g/mol = 3.0285 grams

Here my teacher says it is 3.0285 grams in 1000 ml

Why is it automatically in 1000 ml

I have not done anything

Ps. Sorry if its a bit of stupid question but i just wonder

Answer (score 1):

$\pu{25 mM}$ is not $\pu{0.025 mol}$ ( it would be $\pu{25 mmol}$), but $\pu{0.025 mol/L.}$ As $\mathrm{M}$ in this context means abbreviation for $\pu{mol/L}$ and $\pu{mM}$ for $\pu{mmol/L}$.

By multiplication with the molar mass, you get the mass concentration in $\pu{g/L}$.

$$\pu{\frac{25}{1000} mol L-1} \cdot \pu{121.14 g mol-1} = \pu{3.0285 g L-1}$$